# Удалить первую строку в docx документе через OpenXML

Tags: c#, docx, openxml

Каким образом можно открыть docx документ и удалить оттуда самую первую строку, используя OpenXML?

Или удалить какой-то определенный текст? (я знаю текст этой строки полностью)

Comment: Наверное первый абзац. Потому что "строка"... думаю такого определения нету в OpenXML для текста. Длинна строки зависит от ширины экрана, и расположения елемента "параграф" (w:p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если важна сама суть удаления, то вот код, как это можно сделать.

Сначала подключаем необходимые библиотеки для поддержки OpenXML:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
```

Далее создаём объект типа `WordprocessingDocument` и правами на чтение И запись:

```
WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true);
```

После этого считаем в потоке основное содержимое корневого элемента `document` и запомним:

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(doc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
    {
        text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

После этого осталось заменить (удалить) необходимую строку (данные) и записать обратно в поток. Привожу сразу весь код:

```
using System;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace train
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = @"C:\HelloWorld.docx";
            string pattern = "Hello";
            WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, true);
            string text = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(doc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            {
                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            Regex rg = new Regex(pattern);
            text = rg.Replace(text, "");

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(doc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
            {
                writer.Write(text);
            }
            doc.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```